# Dynamic nested structure arrays

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am attempting to use a set of nested structures; one which defines a single co-ordinate in 3D (`coordinate`) and one which describes certain properties about a rectangle (`rectangle`). The number of rectangles dynamically changes at runtime and malloc is successfully working to assign the rectangle structure array. My issue lies within using the nested structure arrays (`Face_Close` and `Face_Far`) of a fixed size of 4 items, which I can't seem to allocate / use successfully.

Nested structures:

```
//co-ordinate structure
typedef struct coordinate
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
} coordinate;

//rectangle
typedef struct rectangle
{
    coordinate Face_Close[4];
    coordinate Face_Far[4];
    coordinate Rotation_Centre;
    coordinate Normal_To_Plane;
} rectangle;
```

I am allocating the outer structure to a dynamic sized portion of memory using a pointer:

```
struct rectangle **cellArray;
```

The memory for `cellArray` gets successfully allocated and defined at runtime using:

```
cellArray = (rectangle**) malloc(num_Cells * sizeof(rectangle*));
```

While I can assign elements of a singular nested structure instance by using:

```
cellArray[currentCell]->Rotation_Centre.X = X_value;
cellArray[currentCell]->Rotation_Centre.Y = Y_value;
cellArray[currentCell]->Rotation_Centre.Z = Z_value;
```

I can't seem to use the inner structure array for `Face_Close` or `Face_Far`; my code compiles successfully with no warnings but generates a SIGSEGV (Mem Error) error during runtime when attempting either:

```
cellArray[currentCell]->Face_Close[1]->X
```

or

```
cellArray[currentCell]->Face_Close[1].X
```

I have tried the following already:

- Changing `coordinate Face_Far[4];` to `coordinate *(Face_Far[4]);` however this also gives SIGSEGV (Mem Error).
- Changing `coordinate Face_Far[4];` to `int *Face_Far[4];` and using it as a pointer array which also gets allocated using malloc using `cellArray[currentCell]->Face_Close = (coll_rect_coord**) malloc(4 * sizeof(coll_rect_coord *))` however this also gives SIGSEGV (Mem Error).
- Changing `coordinate Face_Far[4];` to `int *Face_Far[4];` and attempting to assign the value the pointer references by `cellArray[currentCell]->Face_Close = &(coll_rect_coord**) malloc(4 * sizeof(coll_rect_coord *))` which restults with an error lvalue required as unary '& operand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate an array of pointers to `rectangle` structures, but you do not make these pointers point to actual structures, allocated of not. In fact these pointers are uninitialized, so dereferencing them has undefined behavior: in your case a segmentation fault.

You should allocate the structures, or make `cellArray` a pointer to an array of `rectangle` and allocate it appropriately:

```c
struct rectangle *cellArray;

cellArray = malloc(num_Cells * sizeof(*cellArray));
```

If `currentCell < num_Cells` you would write:

```
cellArray[currentCell].Rotation_Centre.X = X_value;
cellArray[currentCell].Rotation_Centre.Y = Y_value;
cellArray[currentCell].Rotation_Centre.Z = Z_value;

cellArray[currentCell].Face_Close[1].X = X_value;
...
```